# Mobx - UseEffect hook not executing when item in dependency list is changed

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, mobx

I'm new to React and Mobx.

I want the useEffect hook in the code below to execute whenever the dates are changed. The date variables are inside a store. Whenever I change the date, I expect the useEffect in my component to execute, but it only executes when the component is first initialized.

I added the store as an item in the useEfftcts dependency list, but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my component

```
const TeamDashboard: React.FC<IProps> = ({ teams, teamName, teamSchedule }) => {
  const teamsStore = useContext(TeamsStore);
  const datesStore = useContext(DatesStore);

  let teamIds: number[] = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    teams.map((team) => {
      teamIds.push(team.id);
    });

    teamsStore.loadScheudle(
      teamSchedule,
      teamIds,
      datesStore.startDate,
      datesStore.endDate
    );
  }, [datesStore]);

  return (
    <Container></Container>
  );
};
export default observer(TeamDashboard);
```

Here is my Date Store

```
class DatesStore {
    @observable startDate: Date = new Date();
    @observable endDate: Date = new Date('2021-04-05');

    @action setStartDate = (event: any, data: any, ) => {
        data.value > this.endDate
        ? this.startDate = new Date()
        : this.startDate = data.value === null ? seasonStartDate : data.value;
    }

    @action setEndDate = (event: any, data: any) => {
        console.log(data.value);
        this.endDate = data.value === null ? seasonEndDate : data.value;
    }
}

export default createContext(new DatesStore())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making use of makeAutoObservable from Mobx Version 6 and removing the action and observables decorators resolved the useEffect to execute when the Date changed in my store.
Below is how my code is set up now.

Date Store

```
export default class DatesStore {
    startDate: Date = new Date();
    endDate: Date = new Date();

    constructor() {
        this.endDate.setDate(this.startDate.getDate() + parseInt('30'));
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    setStartDate = (event: any, data: any, ) => {
        data.value > this.endDate
        ? this.startDate = new Date()
        : this.startDate = data.value === null ? seasonStartDate : data.value;
    }

    setEndDate = (event: any, data: any) => {
        this.endDate = data.value === null ? seasonEndDate : data.value;
    }
}
```

Root Store that stores all the stores and a custom hook to use the stores in my components

```
interface Store {
    teamsStore: TeamsStore,
    datesStore: DatesStore
}

export const store: Store = {
    teamsStore: new TeamsStore(),
    datesStore: new DatesStore()
}

export const StoreContext = createContext(store);

export function useStore() {
    return useContext(StoreContext)
}
```

The Component in question

```
const TeamDashboard: React.FC<IProps> = ({ teams, teamName, teamSchedule }) => {
  const { teamsStore, datesStore } = useStore();

  teams.slice().sort((a, b) => b.points - a.points);
  let teamIds: number[] = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    teams.map((team) => {
      teamIds.push(team.id);
    });

    teamsStore.loadScheudle(
      teamSchedule,
      teamIds,
      datesStore.startDate,
      datesStore.endDate
    );
  }, [datesStore.startDate, datesStore.endDate]);

  return (
    <Container></Container>
  );
};
export default observer(TeamDashboard);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is that the `datesStore` isn't changing at all, the object is the same but the values inside are changing.

You can try changing your dependencies like this:

```js
useEffect(()=>{/*your function body*/}, [datesStore.startDate, datesStore.endDate]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, your suggestion did not work.